# Multiple queries for a droplink - removing duplicates

Tags: templates, sitecore-query

So, I have multiple organizations content on my site, they are all grouped into a regional content area, and I also have a global content area.  One of my templates looks into a folder that has a photo item which they can use on their pages, but it's presented to them as a droplink field.  I have it working fine for their individual organization via the following query:

```
query:ancestor::*/Photos//*[@@templateid='{55A41A27-A674-4A04-9716-8E5CB8786A85}']
```

I want to also add to this droplink options for the global and regional photos.  I tried just concatenating, eg:

```
  query:ancestor::*/Photos//*[@@templateid='{55A41A27-A674-4A04-9716-8E5CB8786A85}']|/sitecore/content/All Organizations/Photos//*[@@templateid='{55A41A27-A674-4A04-9716-8E5CB8786A85}']
```

However, this just concatenates two separate queries, which is fine for the individual organization level, but for the global area, it essentially is finding the same items twice, and duplicating them in the droplink.  I'm wondering if there's any way to do essentially a distinct for a this kind of query, or is that just not available?

Comment: I send you a chat invite

Comment: Sorry, not seeing anything?

Comment: I could not get the ancestor:: to work in my processor, since I am in the core database when it is running. So here is functional code, but it will only run on relative queries. Which is not what you asked for,    https://gist.github.com/dnstommy/8372c785b1916900caee2a3d75ca0e34

Comment: Thanks, I have it working as well without the ancestor, can you think of any way I can emulate that in code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to select unique results in Sitecore Query.

But you can do something like this to filter out the results by checking if the "Photos" item id on the "ancestor query" is part of your Global content area

```
query:ancestor::*/Photos[@@id!='{ID of /sitecore/content/All Organizations/Photos}']//*[@@templateid='{55A41A27-A674-4A04-9716-8E5CB8786A85}']|/sitecore/content/All Organizations/Photos//*[@@templateid='{55A41A27-A674-4A04-9716-8E5CB8786A85}']
```